# Angularjs + yeoman login sample application

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am making a application with yeoman plus angular and I am having a few issues. I make the app with simple service call and authentication. The things which I need to know are as follow:

1. How do i redirect after login?
2. How to maintain session after login?
3. Do I need to be on same page or do I need to add new route for it?

Please keep that in mind I am using for all this the route generator and controller.

My app structure is: call is going to controller and controller is giving call to service and service is doing the HTTP request and when the result comes it will print on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer a full REST API with token authentication.

Maybe you can read http://pages.apigee.com/web-api-design-ebook.html or http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do